# How to better factor classes that switch on type code

Tags: refactoring, ruby

We have a persistence backed object, and it has a `version` field
in the database. Assume there's lots of unrelated code in this
class.

```
#
# We're branching on this "version" field, and we return one
# of 2 policies.
#
class Foo
  def policy
    if version == 'a'
      PolicyA.new
    else
      PolicyB.new
    end
  end
end

#
# PolicyA calls a single check on a collaborator.
#
class PolicyA
  def pass?(collaborator)
    collaborator.check_x?
  end
end

#
# PolicyB calls two different checks.
#
class PolicyB
  def pass?(collaborator)
    collaborator.check_x? && collaborator.check_y?
  end
end

#
# One day, we need a 3rd policy version.
#
class Foo
  def policy
    if version == 'a'
      PolicyA.new
    elsif version == 'b'
      PolicyB.new
    else
      PolicyC.new
    end
  end
end

#
# PolicyC needs 2 collaborators, so we add a second argument
# and assign a default.
#
class PolicyA
  def pass?(collaborator_a, _collaborator_b = nil)
    collaborator_a.check_x?
  end
end

#
# Same here.
#
class PolicyB
  def pass?(collaborator_a, _collaborator_b = nil)
    collaborator_a.check_x? && collaborator_a.check_y?
  end
end

#
# Here we pass in a second collaborator and query it.
#
class PolicyC
  def pass?(collaborator_a, collaborator_b)
    collaborator_a.check_y? && collaborator_b.check_z?
  end
end

#
# Some code has to use this thing.
#
class PolicyChecker
  def check(foo)
    foo.policy.pass?(collaborator_a, collaborator_b)
  end
end
```

Is there a good way out of this that doesn't involve
subclassing Foo?

What about dealing with these collaborators? What happens when
a third one comes along?

Reaching into `foo` to get at `policy` feels wrong, but `policy`
knowing about `foo.version` also feels wrong.

Whats a good path forward from here?

Comment: Is the needed implementation of `PolicyA` dependent only on `version == 'a'` or does it need to be version "a" of `Foo`? If I had a `Bar` that was version "a" could I reuse any of this code?

Comment: Its only dependant on version == 'a'. You would not have a 'Bar' with any of Foo's version codes.

Comment: If the policy is only dependent on 'a' and not `Foo` then remove the policy code from `Foo` and make the policies into  services that `Foo` or whatever uses thru a policy interface.

Comment: It feels like a "factory" used at the data mapping layer would be a good solution here, so the class doesn't make the decision. Ultimately, *somebody* has to decide this.

Comment: Any reason you have to create a new policy class every time?  What about simply having the policy class as an instance variable.  If you need to change it you change it, but there is no visible reason why it needs to be created new when you can simply reference it.

Comment: Do you want to refactor all your factory classes which have the purpose of returning instances of possibly different classes depending on circumstances)? No, you don’t. How similar is your PolicyA to a factory class?

Answer (score 1):

The type code is a red herring.

Your situation is that you have three policies A, B and C. A and B are implemented differently, but can be abstracted using the same principle: The caller passes a collaborator, and the policy returns whether the collaborator passes or not. The caller can then proceed with the “pass” information alone and doesn’t care which policy produced it and how.

C is very different: it needs two collaborators presumably to determine if the first one passes. So the caller has to know this, they have to call C differently, and they need to have a second collaborator and what it’s there for - I’d assume this has to be a particular person.

So where do we go from there: It doesn’t fit nicely at all. I’d say the caller just has to write some considerable code to handle the cases. Either by using a switch statement, or by subclassing, or by storing a pointer to code performing the right action.

Answer (score 0):

The `Foo#policy` method seems ok.

I think the main problem is `PolicyX#pass?` method; at the moment it is exposing too much. To use it, you have to know about the collaborators of the `PolicyX class`.

A good solution could be to inject collaborators when you instantiate the object.  Lets make an example with `PolicyC`

```rb
class PolicyC
  def initialize(collaborator_a,collaborator_b)
    @collaborator_a = collaborator_a
    @collaborator_b = collaborator_b
  end
  def pass?
    @collaborator_a.check? && collaborator_b.check? # 
  end
end
```